# Strange behavior in import

Tags: python, package, python-import

I'm having problems in importing a module.
If I use,

```
 import fruit as f
 print f.apple.juice.CALORIES_INT
```

This works.
And

```
 import fruit.apple.juice as j
 print j.CALORIES_INT
```

Doesn't work. It throws `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'apple'`. Any suggestion on how to debug it?

My directory structure looks like:

```
fruit  
--- __init__.py  
--- apple  
---------__init__.py  
--------- juice.py  
---------------CALORIES_INT is a variable declared here  
--- orange  
--------- __init__.py  
--------- shake.py  
---------------trying to access CALORIES_INT here by importing it.
```

apple is a package. I am able to import other package though.

Comment: The problem you encountered is normal Python behaviour, not anything to do with Pyramid. I retagged it for you. :-)

Comment: What is `apple` in this case? It is not a module, I'd say.

Comment: Is `apple.py` really the name of the directory under `fruit`, or is that a typo?

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. Have updated the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `from . import apple` to the `__init__.py` file of your `fruit` package. Alternatively, you could use `from fruit import apple` in the same location.

Nested packages are not automatically made available as attributes of the parent package, this only works after importing the nested package explicitly.

If you first to `import fruit.apple`, then `import fruit; fruit.apple` works. Or you explicitly import the `apple` nested package in the `fruit/__init__.py` file to ensure that `import fruit; fruit.apple` always works for users of your `fruit` package.

The same applies to the `juice` module in the `apple` package; you need to make it available by importing it in the `apple` package `__init__.py`; add a `from . import juice`, or use an absolute import like `from fruit.apple import juice`.

Comment: When I write `import .apple` in `fruit/__init__.py` it throws `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. `import apple` doesn't give error but it throws the same error as previous.

Comment: @cisnik: Sorry, my mistake, fumbled the relative import there, corrected now.

Comment: @cisnik: is there a `apple` subdirectory with a `__init__.py` file inside of your `fruit` directory *at all*? What is `apple`? I do see I may have misread your question (interpreted it the wrong way around), but it looks as if `apple` is an object, not a module.

Comment: can you update your question with that information? It is hard to parse here in a comment. I built some test structures for my original answer, and I did not reproduce your situation.

Comment: @cisnik: Okay, for that structure my original answer works; I've tripple-checked that again locally. Just to verify, the `from fruit import apple` import in `fruit/__init__.py` does not work for you?

Comment: It doesn't throw any error when i import. But the above solution doesn't work when accessing the variable as mentioned (by me).
I have done this now:  
fruit--> __init__.py  
`from fruit import apple`  

when i write `import fruit.apple as fa` in `juice.py` i get importError. But if i do `import fruit as fr` and then   `fr.apple.juice.CALORIES_INT` it works.

Comment: Who said anything about adding imports to `juice.py`? Is the import error triggered in `juice.py` at all?

Comment: The import error is triggered when i try importing anything other than `fruit` in `shake.py`. For ex. `import fruit.apple` or `import fruit.apple.juice` etc. throw import error.

Comment: Yes, I understood that; but did you add the `from fruit import apple` and `from fruit.apple import juice` imports in the `__init__.py` files I indicated? Did those lead to import errors themselves?

Comment: This project is pretty complex. Some other imports and this one fixed the problem. Thanks Martijn. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 from fruit.apple import juice as j
```